# chainlink external-initiator unsupported metadata version 13

Tags: substrate, chainlink, polkadot

i'm trying to connect the external-initiator with my chainlink node,  but here is the error I get when I try to add a new job in the Chainlink node.
This is the logs of my external-initiator:

```
2021-11-09T15:09:14Z [ERROR] Failed testing subscriber: unsupported metadata version 13 client/web.go:192                stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/external-initiator/client.(HttpService).CreateSubscription
    /external-initiator/client/web.go:192
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(Context).Next
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/context.go:152
github.com/smartcontractkit/external-initiator/client.authenticate.func1
    /external-initiator/client/web.go:120
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(Context).Next
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/context.go:152
github.com/Depado/ginprom.(Prometheus).Instrument.func1
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/!depado/ginprom@v1.2.1-0.20200115153638-53bbba851bd8/prom.go:215
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(Context).Next
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/context.go:152
github.com/smartcontractkit/external-initiator/client.loggerFunc.func1
    /external-initiator/client/web.go:259
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(Context).Next
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/context.go:152
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.RecoveryWithWriter.func1
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/recovery.go:83
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(Context).Next
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/context.go:152
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(Engine).handleHTTPRequest
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/gin.go:409
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(Engine).ServeHTTP
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.0/gin.go:367
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2878
net/http.(conn).serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1929
```

1. **How can I check the metadata version of the [external-initiator](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/external-initiator)**, In here I used the latest version in the master branch.
2. **How can I change it to accept metadataV13?** my substrate is using metadataV13

Thank you so much for your helping!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your error is coming from the [Substrate RPC API](https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/search?q=unsupported%20metadata), and not the Chainlink node. Suggest [ensuring you are using the latest version](https://githubmemory.com/repo/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/issues/176) and trying again